# How To Overcome Manual Patches deployment Using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, svn, tomcat6, jboss5.x

Greetings!!

I am new to Maven. My problem is in my company we are used to deploy the patches into production server manually file by file into tomcat web application deployment location .
Due to this there is always an uncertainty about patches.
I came to know that we can use Maven automation deployment, I need a exact procedure to deploy into production server using maven.

Server OS:- windows xp

Web server :apache tomcat 6,jboss 5.x

Version Control:- SVN

Please explain me in detail because I am a beginner in Maven.

Sorry if I spelled anything wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

Maven can create a WAR file for you can install in Tomcat (instead of the file-by-file solution).

For this, you need to convert your application into a Maven project. This isn't exactly a one-step process. Start reading the documentation regarding the [Maven Archetype Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/). That will help you create a sane and clean project structure into which you can copy/merge your existing data.

Maybe create a simple test project that helps you understand how Maven works and what it does and how to map your existing build steps to the new tool.

Afterwards, you'll need to read the documentation for the [Maven WAR Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) which creates the WAR archive.